# Vector push back function

Tags: c++, c++17

I am Trying to push back a number in the vector for using **push_back()** function of vector ,function is taking the number but not adding it to the list

char p is to display the list
char a is to add a number to the list
char m is show mean of the list

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

void display_menu()
{
    cout<<"Enter a character from the list \n P= Display The List \n Q = Quit \n M = Mean \n A = Add Number \n S = Smalles number "<<endl;
}

char selection()
{
    char selection {};
    //char invalid {"invalid"};
    cout<<"Enter A Character From The List : ";
    cin>> selection;
    cout<<endl;
    if(selection == 'p'||selection == 'a'||selection == 'm'||selection == 's'||selection == 'q')
    {
        return toupper(selection);
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Invalid Character , Please Enter Valid One From The List "<<endl;
    }
}
//This Function Will Work According to The Selection
void operation (char selection,vector <int> list) 
{
    if (selection == 'P') //Print The List
    {
        cout<<"(";
        for(auto i:list)
        {
            cout<<i;
        }
        cout<<")";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    else if (selection == 'A') // To Add A Number Into The List
    {
        int number;
        cout<<"Enter A Number To Add To The List : ";
        cin>>number;
        list.push_back(number);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"A number is added to the list"<<endl;

    }
    else if(selection == 'M') //To Get The Mean Of The List
    {
        int result = 0;
        double mean;
        for(auto i:list)
        {
            result += i;
        }
        mean = result / list.size();
        cout<<mean<<endl;    
    }
    else if(selection == 'S')
    {
        int smallest_number = 0;
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= list.size() ; i++)
        {
            if(list[i] < list[i-1])
            {
                smallest_number = list[i];
            }
            else
            {
                smallest_number = list[0];
            }
        }
        cout<<smallest_number<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> data {1,2,3,4};
    char select {};
    while(select != 'Q')
    {
        display_menu();
        select = selection();
        operation(select,data);
    }



}
```

Any Help Will Be Very appriciable....... I'm stuck,couldn't find a way to fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to receive the vector by reference in `operation` function

```
operation (char selection,vector <int> list)
```

Change the above function to

```
void operation (char selection,vector <int> &list)
```